# time diff when group changes in r

Tags: r, time

I want to calculate the total amount of time spent within each site (from each entry to each exit).

```
Site<-c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,2,1,2)
start_date <- as.Date('2015-01-01')  
end_date <- as.Date('2015-12-30')   
set.seed(1990)
DetTime<-as.Date(sample( as.numeric(start_date): as.numeric(end_date), 10, 
                replace = T), 
        origin = '1970-01-01')
df<-data.frame(Site,DetTime=sort(DetTime))
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
      Site    DetTime
1     1 2015-01-15
2     1 2015-02-22
3     1 2015-03-04
4     2 2015-03-18
5     2 2015-03-23
6     3 2015-04-22
7     3 2015-05-12
8     2 2015-07-18
9     1 2015-08-05
10    2 2015-10-22
```

I want the time difference when sites change and NOT just aggregating by site. I need the difference in time from the first detection time in a site to the first detection time in the next site (not the last detection in the original site).

Doing this manually for the example would appear like this:

```
difftime(df[4,2],df[1,2]) # total is 62 days in section 1
difftime(df[6,2],df[4,2]) # total is 35 days in section 2
difftime(df[8,2],df[6,2]) # total is 87 days in section 3
difftime(df[9,2],df[8,2]) # total is 18 days in section 2
difftime(df[10,2],df[9,2]) # total is 78 days in section 1
```

Then I would like to take the sum for each section.

Comment: You created a matrix, not a `data.frame`. Don't use `cbind`, but just simply do `df <- data.frame(Site, DetTime)`

Comment: Do you want to find out the total time spent at each site? (why do you need difftime of row 4 and 1?)

Comment: Want to help but it's confusing since the times are not in descending order.  For instance, the difftime of row 4 and 6 would yield a negative number.  Can't really figure out what logic to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach with data.table:

```
# convert to datatable
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# keep only first row by Site, create lag, take difference
df2 <- df[ , .(DetTime = min(DetTime)), by=rleid(Site)]
df2[ , next_start := shift(DetTime, type="lead")]
df2[ , total_time := next_start - DetTime]
```

Result:

```
> df2

   rleid    DetTime next_start total_time
1:     1 2015-01-15 2015-03-18    62 days
2:     2 2015-03-18 2015-04-22    35 days
3:     3 2015-04-22 2015-07-18    87 days
4:     4 2015-07-18 2015-08-05    18 days
5:     5 2015-08-05 2015-10-22    78 days
6:     6 2015-10-22       <NA>    NA days
```

Comment: Dan, I appreciate the input and although this will calculate the correct min(DetTime) within each site it does not use the first detection time of the next site as the maximum(DetTime).